# Bitbucket, Dploy.io and Grunt

Tags: git, deployment, gruntjs, bitbucket

Current situation:
I push something to my production branch, [dploy](http://dploy.io) automatically deploys it. This all works.

However, I would like to minify my code (using grunt) before it is deployed, but do not want to manually run `grunt build` every time before making a commit, it would be cumbersome. What I want to happen is the following: I push a commit to the production branch, something is set in motion to run grunt's build task and the result of this is then deployed; instead of the original source code.

How would I do this?

Edit:
I am okay with ditching Dploy if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using [Grunt Githooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks)

To install: `npm install grunt-githooks --save-dev`

And to load it: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-githooks');`

And then in your config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  githooks: {
    all: {
      'pre-commit': 'build',
    }
  }
});
```

After adding this to `Gruntfile.js` you will need to run `grunt githooks` one time to create the files that git will check prior to your commit. You'll also want to run that command any time you make changes to your githooks rules.

Now anytime you make a commit the pre-commit grunt tasks you specified will run.

I'm a product designer at Wildbit (we make Dploy.io), so if you run into any issues please don't hesitate to reply here or contact our fantastic support staff (seriously, they're great).